# vscode debugger not working with multiple files

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code

When i hit F5 to run debugger in vscode, the debug screen (top bar and terminal) shows for 1 second before it disappears. This seems to only happen when I call functions that are defined in another c file. For example, this is not working:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
    printFoo();
    return 0;
}
```

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void printFoo();

#endif
```

**foo.c**

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void printFoo() {
    printf("Foo");
}
```

But if I place the `printFoo()` definition in `foo.h` the debugger runs normally. What causes this problem, and how can I fix it?

I suspect that I need to set up a launch.json (not very familiar with that), but when I click "create a launch.json file" it creates an empty file without any configurations.

I'm using mingw-w64.

Edit:
Here is my **tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: [Using GCC with MinGW](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).

Comment: What messages do you see in the output window? Did you modify `tasks.json` to compiler multiple files?

Comment: I get "undefined reference to 'printFoo' " in the vscode terminal, nothing in the output window. I have not modified tasks.json

Comment: You only build with the current file. You need to build with *both* source files.

Comment: I changed `"${file}"` to `"${fileDirname}\\**.c"` and now it's working. Thank you!